# Exit transition in translucent activity

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm trying to do a simple fade out transition when a translucent activity. The style of the activity is:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

Fade in enter transition works smoothly but fade out exit transition after calling `finishAfterTransition()` just blinks between my current (translucent) activity and the previous one.

I got it working performing a regular animation on the layout and then finishing the activity. But I would really like to know how to do it with the Transition Framework on activities.

Comment: Did you try `<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/exit</item>`?

Comment: Yes, it does the same blink effect.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can implement fade-in and fade-out animation by this way also.     
 Create anim folder under res folder, In anim folder create two xml file.
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     fadein.xml

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="2000" />
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       fadeout.xml

       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:
    duration="2000" />

     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Add this on override method of onCreate and onStart.

     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);


     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

            }


     @Override
        protected void onStart() {

            super.onStart();

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
           }
```

Comment: Thanks @vishal-sharma. I know I can achieve it this way. But I would like to know how to dit with the transition framework. I would like to know why `window.exitTransition = Fade(Fade.MODE_OUT)` is not working in case of a translucent activity.

Answer (score -1):

While performing Transitions on Translucent Activities the default `exitTransition`'s behavior inherits from the `enterTransition`, Actually, it reverses the transition and we cannot override it.

Luckily, there is one another property available which plays an important role for the activity's closing transition i.e. `returnTransition` which is the desired Transition used to move Views out of the scene when the Window is preparing to close.

Now instead of `window.exitTransition = Fade(Fade.MODE_OUT)` try using the

> window.returnTransition = Fade(Fade.MODE_OUT)

or you can override it in activity's theme defined in your ***styles.xml***

> `<item name="android:windowReturnTransition">@transition/exit_transition</item>`

where your ***exit_transition.xml*** would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <fade
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:fadingMode="fade_out" />
</transitionSet>
```

inside the ***res/transition*** directory. And you're ready to rock!